# Why is my Flask server returning a 400 error?

Tags: python, flask

Does anyone have any idea why a PATCH request to my flask server would return a 400 error? I'm sending json data. The POST request works fine.

Thanks in advance!

```
@app.route('/pokedex/add/', methods=["POST", "PATCH"])
def add_pokemon():
    conn = get_db_connection()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    if request.method =='PATCH':
        try:
            cur.execute("UPDATE pokedex_mon SET caught = True WHERE name=" + request.json['name'])
            conn.commit()
            cur.close()
            conn.close()
            return jsonify(True)
        except:
            return jsonify(False)
    else:
        if (request.json['caught'] == True):
            caught = True
        else:
            caught = False
        try:
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO pokedex_mon (name,description,image,seen,caught) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', (request.json['name'], request.json['description'], request.json['image'], True, caught))
            conn.commit()
            cur.close()
            conn.close()
            return jsonify(True)
        except:
            return jsonify(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over writing the default 'GET' method in @app.route .
Write 'GET' also with 'POST' and 'PATCH'.
I am not sure but it might be the problem.

Comment: This did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the stacktrace. I guess that this line caused an error:

```py
cur.execute("UPDATE pokedex_mon SET caught = True WHERE name=" + request.json['name'])
```

Suppose `request.json['name']` equals `test`, then your sql will be `UPDATE pokedex_mon SET caught = True WHERE name=test`.

`name=test` is wrong, it should be `name='test'`.

By the way, you'd better not concat sql parameters by hand, the best practice is to use `parameterized queries`.

Answer (score 0):

the way you construct your sql query in the POST is better for multiple reasons

check if this fixes it:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE pokedex_mon SET caught = True WHERE name=%s", (request.json['name']),)
```

also, to better debug this, I recommend catching the error (if there is one) like this:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

you could even jsonify and return the error, but I wouldn't recommend that, unless it really helps you in your workflow.